# form starting but not displaying vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So I was coding a program that opens 20 web browsers on one page, for a youtube or view bot any URL really, but when I launched the program It displayed the text box I put in to see if it was actually starting and then nothing else

So my question is, Whats wrong with my code?

startup form (where you can launch the main code with button 1)

```
Public Class Startup

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)                                   Handles Button2.Click
    Settings.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    views.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

main form

```
Public Class views

Private Sub views_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MessageBox.Show("Form Initalised")
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser2.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser3.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser4.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser5.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser6.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser7.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser8.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser9.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser10.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser11.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser12.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser13.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser14.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser15.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser16.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser17.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser18.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser19.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    WebBrowser20.Navigate(My.Settings.url)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(My.Settings.Time)
    reload.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

and form reload mentioned in the main form.

```
Public Class reload

Private Sub reload_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Close()
    views.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `So my question is, Whats wrong with my code?` To be honest (with all due respect) I think everything is wrong. The `Startup` class seems OK though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the Form.Shown event instead of the Form.Load event. In Form.Load the controls are often not fully initialized and if something goes wrong there the initialization of the whole form sometimes goes awry. It's better to use the Form.Shown for such lengthy procedures you have there.